# How to fix Else if function in google script?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets, syntax-error

I am trying to write a code where an email will be sent to different people when single a row has been edited at different columns on google sheets.

For example, if column 8 has been edited it should send an email to ABC. Then ABC writes "APPROVE" in column 13 and an email sends to XYZ.

I am trying to use the else if function to separate the two trigger events but when I click save on Google Script, it says the

> Syntax error: SyntaxError: Unexpected token 'else' line.

```
   function sendMailEdit(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("REVIEW");
   const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,20).getValues();

   ...
   
   if (e.range.columnStart == 8);{
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "ABC@gmail.com",
     subject: "New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg,
     noReply: true
   });
   }
     
   else if (e.range.columnStart == 13 || e.value == "APPROVED");{
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "XYZ@gmail.com",
     subject: "New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg2,
     noReply: true
   });
   }
}
```

Comment: I have to apologize for my poor English skill. About `For example, if column 8 has been edited it should send an email to ABC. Then ABC writes "APPROVE" in column 13 and an email sends to XYZ.`, do you want to send 2 emails for "ABC" and "XYZ" by one execution?

Comment: @Tanaike I want to send two different emails to two different people when there are two different trigger events

Comment: Thank you for replying. Now, I noticed that your question has already been resolved. I'm glad about it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not test the code, but after reviewing your code in the editor I noticed that you had extra ";" after if parentheses. After removing the parentheses the code saved was successfully.

Change your code from:

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("REVIEW");
   const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,20).getValues();

   ...
   
   if (e.range.columnStart == 8);{
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "ABC@gmail.com",
     subject: "New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg,
     noReply: true
   });
   }
     
   else if (e.range.columnStart == 13 || e.value == "APPROVED");{
   MailApp.sendEmail({
     to: "XYZ@gmail.com",
     subject: "New Account Access Request",
     htmlBody: msg2,
     noReply: true
   });
   }
}
```

to:

```
function sendMailEdit(e){
   var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("REVIEW");
   const rData = e.source.getActiveSheet().getRange(e.range.rowStart,1,1,20).getValues();

   ...
    
   if (e.range.columnStart == 8){
    MailApp.sendEmail({
      to: "ABC@gmail.com",
      subject: "New Account Access Request",
      htmlBody: msg,
      noReply: true});
   } else if (e.range.columnStart == 13 || e.value == "APPROVED"){
      MailApp.sendEmail({
        to: "XYZ@gmail.com",
        subject: "New Account Access Request",
        htmlBody: msg2,
        noReply: true});
   }
}
```

Comment: Thanks! Works now. 
Was not aware you are not supposed to buy the ```;``` there, I've included it in previous scripts and worked fine.